# How to prove the equation below?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a matrx $X_{n\times p}$, how to prove equation as follow:
$$X(X^{T}X+\lambda^{-1}I_p)^{-1}X^{T}=XX^{T}(XX^{T}+\lambda^{-1}I_n)^{-1}$$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.

Comment: What does this mean: "Proving an equation"?

Comment: @zoli It means proving that the equation holds for any matrix $X$

Comment: @zili yes, it means this equation holds for any matrix X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** One approach is as follows.  Observe that for any polynomial $f$, we have
$$
Xf(X^TX)X^T = XX^Tf(XX^T).
$$
Because $X^TX$ and $XX^T$ are diagonalizable with the same non-zero eigenvalues, the minimal polynomial of one divides the other, which means that we will have 
$$
(XX^T + \lambda^{-1}I_n)^{-1} = f(XX^T)\\
(X^TX + \lambda^{-1}I_p)^{-1} = f(X^TX)
$$ 
for some polynomial $f$.

---

Another approach, if you'd instead like to use an explicit function instead of an undetermined polynomial, is to note that
$$
(X^TX + \lambda^{-1}I_p)^{-1} = \lambda(\lambda X^TX + I_p)^{-1} = \lambda\sum_{k=0}^\infty
 (-1)^k(\lambda X^TX)^k\\
(XX^T + \lambda^{-1}I_n)^{-1} = \lambda(\lambda XX^T + I_n)^{-1} = \lambda\sum_{k=0}^\infty
 (-1)^k(\lambda XX^T)^k
$$
it is important, however, to note that the infinite series above can only be guaranteed to converge for sufficiently small $\lambda$.

---

Yet another approach: by the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), we have
$$
(X^TX + \lambda^{-1}I_p)^{-1} = \lambda I_p - \lambda^{2}X^T(I_n + \lambda XX^T)^{-1}X
$$
It follows that
$$
\begin{align*}
X(X^TX + \lambda^{-1}I_p)^{-1}X^T &= 
\lambda XX^T - \lambda^{2}(XX^T)(I_n + \lambda XX^T)^{-1}(XX^T)\\
&= XX^T[\lambda I_n - \lambda(I_n + \lambda XX^T)^{-1}(\lambda XX^T)]\\
&= XX^T[\lambda I_n - \lambda(I_n + \lambda XX^T)^{-1}((I_n + \lambda XX^T) - I_n)]\\
&= XX^T[\lambda I_n - \lambda(I_n + \lambda XX^T)^{-1}(I_n + \lambda XX^T) + \lambda(I_n + XX^T)^{-1}]\\
&= XX^T[\lambda I_n - \lambda I_n + \lambda (I_n + \lambda XX^T)^{-1}]\\
&= XX^T [\lambda (I_n + \lambda XX^T)^{-1}]\\
&= XX^T (\lambda^{-1} I_n + XX^T)^{-1}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much giving me these hints. But I still cannot figure out how woodbury matrix identity can prove that equation. I try your method but still fail. Could you give me more details, Thanks again.

Comment: @CalebJin The matrix identity was more of an afterthought, so I didn't think that approach through as thoroughly as I should have.  First of all, I misapplied the formula: I was missing the $A^{-1}$ in the second set of parentheses; the equation in the most recent edit is correct. Second, the approach was more difficult to use than I had expected; I've added the steps in now. Let me know if there's anything else you'd like cleared up.

Comment: Your first approach is brilliant. (But the two occurrences of $(\cdots + \lambda^{-1}I_n)$ should read $(\cdots + \lambda^{-1}I_n)^{-1}$.)

Comment: @user1551 Thank you! (and thank you.)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you so much. Now I fully understand this process by using Woodbury matrix identity.