# If $f(AA^*) = 0$ then $f(A^*A) = 0$

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $f\in \mathbb{C}[x]$. In this case if $f(AA^*) = 0$ then $f(A^*A) = 0$

Here's my solution: It's enough to prove it for polynomials of degree 1 because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. If $f(AA^*) = 0$ then $AA^* = cE$. Then, if $AA^* = (A^*A)^*$, we have $A^*A = \overline{c}E$. But if $c$ is a root, so is $\overline{c}$, then $f(A^*A) = 0$

Is this solution right?

Comment: Why is it enough to show it for polynoms of degree 1? Also $c$ is a root of what?

Comment: I don't see how $\mathbb C$ being algebraically closed lets you reduce it to the case of degree $1$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Because if a field is algebraically closed, then every polynomial can be represented as a product of polynomials of degree 1. $c$ is a root of $f = x - c$, where $c\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: @RonaldSMerritt Most complex matrices (among which the vast majority of the matrices that may be written as $AA^*$) don't annihilate any polynomial of degree $1$.

Comment: @Gae.S. But we're not talking about all matrices. I'm just saying if it's true for $AA^*$ then it's also true for $A^*A$

Comment: @RonaldSMerritt Let $A,B$ be arbitrary $2 \times 2$ matrices that are not multiples of the identity.  It is vacuously true that for every degree one polynomial, $f(A) = 0 \iff f(B) = 0$.  The same need not hold, however, for degree $2$ polynomials.

Comment: @Ronald The point being made here is that there is no clear way to go from the statement "for all $f$ of degree 1: if $f(A^*A) = 0$, then $f(AA^*) = 0$" to the statement "for all polynomials $f$: if $f(A^*A) = 0$, then $f(AA^*) = 0$".

Comment: @Ronald I think that in the back of your head, you're thinking of something like this: "if $f(A^*A) = 0$, then there exists a degree one polynomial $g$ (dividing $f$) such that $g(A^*A) = 0$".  If this is what you're thinking, then perhaps you should try to convince yourself that this is not the case.

Comment: Take any nilpotent matrix $B \ne 0$ ($B^m = 0$ for some $m > 1$). Then for $f(z) = z^m$ you have $f(B) = 0$, but for the linear factors $g(z) = z$ of $f$ you do not have $g(B) = 0$. This shows that your argument does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, your reasoning is not sound.

One approach that works is to start by noting that $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ have the same eigenvalues. We can do either by proving that $AB$ and $BA$ always have the same non-zero eigenvalues and that $A^*A$ and $AA^*$ have the same rank, or by noting that the eigenvalues of $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ are both the squares of the singular values of $A$.  By the spectral theorem, $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ are diagonalizable, which means that the matrices will satisfy $f(X) = 0$ if and only if the zeros of $f(x)$ include this common set of eigenvalues.

---

A possible solution that avoids the spectral theorem: note that by the symmetry of the problem, it suffices to show that $f(AA^*) = 0 \implies f(A^*A) = 0$.

With that in mind, suppose that $f(x) = \sum_{j}c_jx^j$ is such that $f(AA^*) = 0$. Suppose that $A$ is invertible.  Then we have
$$
0 = f(A^*A) =  \sum_{j=0}^n c_j(A^*A)^j = c_0 I + \sum_{j=1}^n c_j(A^*A)^j
= c_0 I + A^*\left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j(AA^*)^{j-1}\right)A \implies\\
0 = c_0A^{-1} + A^*\left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j(AA^*)^{j-1}\right) \implies\\
0 = c_0 I  + AA^*\left(\sum_{j=1}^n c_j(AA^*)^{j-1}\right) =
c_0 I + \sum_{j=1}^n c_j(AA^*)^{j} = f(AA^*).
$$
I am not sure how to extend this to the case where $A$ is singular. I suspect that we can do something using the [Moore-Penrose pseudinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) $A^+$ in place of $A^{-1}$, but that seems to defeat the purpose of avoiding the spectral theorem.

I also think we could use the fact that the restriction of $A^*A$ to its image is invertible, which seems more in the spirit of the proof.

Comment: [This answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3302058/81360) comes to mind, but I'm not sure if it's relevant