# Resolvent matrix of the product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

LEt $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ be a positive definite matrix, and $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$ be a rectangular matrix. Consider the following resolvent matrix:
$$
\mathbf{G}(z) = (z \mathbf{I}_M - \mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{X} \mathbf{Y} )^{-1}
$$

Is there any relation between this resolvent and resolvents of $\mathbf{X}$ and/or $\mathbf{Y}^T \mathbf{Y}$?

Comment: Possibly useful: from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3302042/81360), we have
$$
M(zI - M^TM)^{-1}M^T = MM^T(MM^T + z I)^{-1}
$$
We can apply this with $M = X^{1/2}Y$.