# Is there a setup in which is the Woodbury formula actually useful?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

Let $A, C, U, V$ denote matrices of suitable sizes and let $A, C$ be invertible. Then Woodbury formula states that
$$
 \left(A + UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1} + VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}.
$$
The formula can be obtained by considering the inversion of the block system with a matrix
$$
\mathcal{A} = \begin{bmatrix} A & U \\ V & -C \end{bmatrix}.
$$
In my experience coming from finite elements, it is actually better to study the system given by $\mathcal{A}$ than to apply the formula.

The special case with $C$ being a $1 \times 1$ matrix (Sherman–Morrison formula) is sometimes useful. My question is if there are settings with higher ranks of $C$ in which the Woodbury formula is typically used or considered useful.

Edit: This question is actually sort of a duplicate of [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99349/woodbury-formula), some numerical concerns can be found in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80340/special-considerations-when-using-the-woodbury-matrix-identity-numerically).

Comment: Tangential: the resolvent identity is very useful and is closely related.

Comment: @Korf What exactly do you mean by "useful"? Probably the most important/common application is as a means of more quickly obtaining the inverse of the matrix. Finding the inverse of a matrix with size equal to that of $C$ can be significantly faster than directly finding the inverse of a matrix.

Comment: @Korf Or to reframe the question, in what way did you consider studying the block-system to be "better"?

Comment: @Korf I'm not sure it's particularly persuasive, but [this was a problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3302058/81360) where the Woodbury formula led to a neat approach towards a proof

Comment: @Korf Also, shouldn't that block system have the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{A & U\\ V & -C^{-1}}?
$$
I'm not aware of an approach using the block matrix as you have it

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for catching the typo (should be fixed now) and the link. The linked answer is quite inspiring! Would be nice to see where did that questions OP run into their problem.

Comment: The block system is afaik "better" in the FEM context where the matrices are big, sparse and sizes of $A$ and $C$ are comparable and using direct solves is relatively costly. You can usually show some properties of the individual blocks and construct preconditioners for iterative solution methods. I am aware that this is a an extreme case and can see that the formula might be nice when size of $C$ is small compared to $A$. I'd be happy to see some practical application.